# How do I write an algorithm to cut nodes while preserving a NetworkX network?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

Assume I have a simple network as follows, and I want to remove the lower case nodes while preserving the overall structure. How do I do that? Here's some sample code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph();
G.add_edge("A","b")
G.add_edge("b","C")
G.add_edge("b","D")
G.add_edge("D","e")
G.add_edge("e","F")


def printHackyDot(x):
    for n in x.nodes():
        for pre in x.predecessors(n):
            print(pre + " -> " + n)

printHackyDot(G)
badNodes = [n for n in G.nodes if str.islower(n)]
```

Running this will yield:

```
A -> b
b -> C
b -> D
D -> e
e -> F
```

i.e.

[image: This digraph]

How do I write f(G) such that I get a similar, simplified graph less lowercase nodes:

```
A -> C
A -> D
D -> F
```

[image: What I want]

I tried the following, but it fails when you have two lower case in a row:

```
for badNode in [x for x  in list(G.nodes) if str.islower(x)]:
    R.remove_node(badNode)
    for predNode in G.predecessors(badNode):
        for succNode in G.successors(badNode):
            R.add_edge(predNode,succNode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it, iff the graph is a DAG. Someone clever could fix this req.

```
def isBadNode(x):
    return str.islower(x)

def goodPreds(X,node):
    return [n for n in X.predecessors(node) if not isBadNode(n)]+[gn for n in X.predecessors(node) for gn in goodPreds(X,n) if isBadNode(n)]

def goodSuccs(X,node):
    return [n for n in X.successors(node) if not isBadNode(n)]+[gn for n in X.successors(node) for gn in goodSuccs(X,n) if isBadNode(n)]

R= G.copy()
for badNode in [x for x  in list(R.nodes) if isBadNode(x)]:
    for predNode in goodPreds(G,badNode):
        for succNode in goodSuccs(G,badNode):
            R.add_edge(predNode,succNode)
    R.remove_node(badNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `R` starts off as a copy of `G`?

This would work if you replace

```
for badNode in [x for x  in list(G.nodes) if str.islower(x)]:
    R.remove_node(badNode)
    for predNode in G.predecessors(badNode):
        for succNode in G.successors(badNode):
            R.add_edge(predNode,succNode)
```

with  (**edited for bug deleting `badNode` too soon**)

```
for badNode in [x for x  in list(R.nodes) if str.islower(x)]:
    for predNode in R.predecessors(badNode):
        for succNode in R.successors(badNode):
            R.add_edge(predNode,succNode)
    R.remove_node(badNode)
```

The issue is that when you handle the first of two lower case nodes in a row it removes that node.  But when you handle the other one, it's seeing that in `G` that node has a lower case neighbor, and it puts the edge back.  If you look at it's neighbors in `R` you'll handle it correctly.

Comment: Nope, deletes the node before it can reattach

Comment: try G.add_edge("A","b")
G.add_edge("b","C")
G.add_edge("b","D")
G.add_edge("D","e")
G.add_edge("e","f")
G.add_edge("f","G")